# Access flashattribute in Springflow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow-2

Added value to `redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("some", value);` and then redirect to `Springflow`

How to access `flashattribute` `some` in `Springflow`?

```
<on-start>
 <evaluate expression="do.Action(???)" result="flowScope.someobject" />
</on-start>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216312/accessing-flash-attributes-in-spring-web-flow

Comment: It talks about adding but how to access in flow XML?

Comment: requestScope.some or requestScope['some']

Comment: From the previous link I shared try adding it to viewScope instead. context.getViewScope().put("some", some),  and then access it in flow xml with viewScope.some or viewScope['some']

Comment: My apologies for delayed response. The problem with that approach is, its a redirect from Spring Controller and Flow Context is not available in Controller. So that approach would not work either.

Comment: did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Sorry for a late response. Best solution!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<evaluate expression="webFlowUtils.getFlashAttribute(externalContext, 'some')"/>
```

with:

```
@Component
public final class WebFlowUtils {

    public Object getFlashAttribute(ExternalContext context, String attributeName) {
        Map<String, ?> flashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap((HttpServletRequest) context.getNativeRequest());
        return flashMap != null ? flashMap.get(attributeName) : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Really appreciate. And thanks a lot :)