# File upload with Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

I have searched and read multiple answers on `file upload` using `Spring Web Flow` but all seems to give same result. Hence posting.

```
public class FileUploadForm {
    private transient MultipartFile file;

    //Additional fields
}
```

Flow

```
<view-state id="start" model="fileUploadForm">
    <transition on="submit" to="submit"/>
    <transition on="cancel" to="cancel"/>
</view-state>

<action-state id="submit">
    <evaluate expression="someActions.review(fileUploadForm)" />
    <transition on="success" to="home"/>
</action-state>
```

JSP

`<form:form modelAttribute="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
        <form:label path="file">Upload File</form:label>
        <form:input type="file" path="file"/>
        <button name="_eventId_upload">Upload Button</button>
    </form:form>`

XML

```
<!--<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">-->
    <!--<property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>-->
<!--</bean>-->

<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
</bean>
```

JAVA

```
public String review(FileUploadForm fileUploadForm) {
    LOG.info("{}", fileUploadForm.getFile().getContentType());
    return "success";
}
```

At `LOG.info` `getFile` is null. I do get other fields filled in the form, but not the file field.

Can someone please point me in the right direction. Using `Webflow 2.5.1`

Comment: do you have getters and setters in `FileUploadForm`?

Comment: Yes, its a regular POJO

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular input file:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
```

[EDIT] to be complete, my working code also uses this form tag:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="fileUploadForm" action="${flowExecutionUrl}&${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and this type of submit button:

```
<input type="submit" id="upload" name="_eventId_upload" value="Upload"></span>
```

Comment: This did not work. Still thankful to your past solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635640/access-flashattribute-in-springflow

Comment: This did not work. But I will try again and give more feedback.